# Find the integral $\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2-x}{x^7}}dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the integral
$$\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2-x}{x^7}}dx $$

Could not find a correct solution.

Comment: I tried to separate (2-x)/x^7 inside the root. But could not come up with something that would keep me going

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
I=\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2-x}{x^7}}dx=\int_{1}^{2}\frac1{x^2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2-x}{x}}dx
\end{align}

Here you could then use $\frac{2-x}{x}=u^3$ which implies $x=2(1+u^3)^{-1}$ and $dx=-6u^2(1+u^3)^{-2}$ so that your integral becomes

\begin{align}
I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1+u^3)^2}{4}\times u\times 6u^2(1+u^3)^{-2} du
\end{align}

Comment: Oh now it is much easier to solve. Thanks

Comment: you welcome ... in general you should almost alway get rid of roots if you can ...

Comment: @Math-fun: Are you sure of your coefficients? We globally have the same method, with a slightly different implementation, but I can't find my error.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Set $u=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2-x}{x}}\iff u^3=\dfrac{2-x}{x}==\dfrac{2}{x}-1$.

Differentiating, we obtain
$\quad3u^2\,\mathrm du=-\dfrac{2}{x^2}\,\mathrm d x,\enspace\text{whence}\quad\mathrm d x= -\dfrac32u^2x^2\,\mathrm du $, so
$$\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2-x}{x^7}}\,\mathrm d x=-\frac32\int_{1}^{0}\frac1{x^2}\,u\cdot u^2x^2\,\mathrm du=\frac32\int_{0}^{1}u^3\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: Your answer provides twice the value :-) I could take the liberty of correcting, shall I?

Comment: @Math-fun: You could, of course, no problem, but I've just found I repeated a `2` on extracting $x^6$ from the cubic root.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2-x}{x^7}}dx=\int_{1}^{2}\frac1{x^2}\sqrt[3]{\frac2x-1}dx$$

Now choose $\frac2x-1=u\implies-\dfrac2{x^2}dx=du$

$$I=-\dfrac12\int_1^0u^{-1/3}du=?$$